# Save Uploaded images to current order table

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, forms, data, attachment

I am Creating an image attachment for each order in admin panel. I have used the image up loader and saved that images to a custom directory as follows:

```
 public function uploadAction() {
    if (isset($_FILES['docname']['name']) && $_FILES['docname']['name'] != '') {

        try {
            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('docname');
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('doc','pdf','txt','docx','png'));
            $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
            $newDir = "customer_documents";

            $newdirPath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . "customer_documents";

            if (!file_exists($newdirPath)) {
                mkdir($newdirPath, 0777);
            }

            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $newDir . DS;
            $resizedPath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $newDir;
            $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['docname']['name']);
            echo $filename = $uploader->getUploadedFileName(); // Uploaded File name
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('core')->__('File uploaded successfully.'));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('core')->__('Unable to find item to save'));
        }
    }
```

But Now I want to save this image to the current order table in database and then i will show it on the account page each user who's order it will be.

This is my tab in order view page admin panel:

```
class MageSf_OrderCustom_Block_Adminhtml_Order_View_Tab_OrderCustom
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{    
//change _constuct to _construct()
public function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('magsf/ordercustom/order/view/tab/ordercustom.phtml');

}

public function getTabLabel() {
    return $this->__('Order Attachment');
}

public function getTabTitle() {
    return $this->__('Order Attachment');
}

public function canShowTab() {
    return true;
}

public function isHidden() {
    return false;
}

public function getOrder(){
    return Mage::registry('current_order');
}
}
```

And here is my form that for uploading the image:

```
<form id="doc-form" name="doc-form" method="post" action="<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/sfupload/upload',array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Upload Document</label>
<input type="file" title="File" name="docname">
<button type="submit" title="Save"><span>Upload</span></button>                    
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add order id in your form

`$this->getOrder()->getId()`

```
<form id="doc-form" name="doc-form" method="post" action="<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/sfupload/upload',array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(),'order_id'=>$this->getOrder()->getId())); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Upload Document</label>
<input type="file" title="File" name="docname">
<button type="submit" title="Save"><span>Upload</span></button>                    
</form>
```

in your `uploadAction`

```
$orderid= $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
```

Comment: After adding the order ID the url becomes as "http://127.0.0.1:8080/magento-1-testing/index.php/admin/sfupload/upload/form_key/MbZUnB0tSEd7lcL1/0/order_id/1/3/key/94a0c3152e30401a8df8de6279c48ac7/2/order_id/3/3/"
but when i print the order id in controller it gives nothing.

Comment: this part worked fine. let me proceed further and see what happened. thanks for this one.